# Appcelerator getting a SQLite database to backup and restore with iCloud Backup

Tags: ios, sqlite, appcelerator, icloud, appcelerator-titanium

My app is live on the app store and users are reporting they cannot see their data after restoring the app to a new or reset iOS device.

The app uses a SQLite database created in the default `Library/Private Documents` folder by Appcelerator SDK.

I've set the `remoteBackup = true` flag on the database file, but I'm confused as to whether Apple even backs up from this folder, or whether the database needs to be in the `Documents` folder to be included in backup?

It should be noted that the database is likely to remain quite small, say 200-300Kb.

Has anyone employed a successful strategy to ensure locally stored SQLite data restores ok?

Comment: In [this guide](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Working_with_a_SQLite_Database-section-29004901_WorkingwithaSQLiteDatabase-Creatingadatabase) it's suggested that what you do should enable (which is even the default) iCloud backup. If you see otherwise then it looks like you've found a bug. Please check if this is a known issue at the [Appcelerator JIRA](https://jira.appcelerator.org/). If it's not, create a ticket, link to this question but also provide reproducible code, steps and environment information in the ticket itself.

Comment: Thanks. I've submitted 2 different tickets to Apple tech support and both times they didn't give me any help, instead just refunding the tickets to my developer account. It seems impossible to test iCloud backup/restore using development or TestFlight builds as they get ignored AFAIK. Having to release an update to the App Store just to test it seems like a bad idea 

Comment: Can the backup flag be set on a directory? Maybe Library/Private Documents doesn't have the flag set even though the contained file does? I'm using Ti SDK 5.2.0 BTW

Comment: @Fokke-Appcelerator I just got this back from Apple: Based on your request Apple Developer Technical Support believes that your question is answered by the “App Backup Best Practices” section of the iOS App Programming Guide linked here:

[link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/PerformanceTips/PerformanceTips.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW17)  - note it doesn't really mention about what happens to other subfolders of Library such as Private Documents.

Comment: OK, could you create a JIRA ticket so that our engineers can look into if indeed databases are not properly backed up and/or restored with iCloud?

Comment: @Fokke-Appcelerator - what am I doing wrong - I'm logged into JIRA (my first time raising a ticket) and have set current Project to TIMOB. When I click Create my only Project choices in the Create Issue popup dialog are Appcelerator - INBOX (AC) and Aptana Studio (APSTUD). Should I be able to choose Titanium SDK & CLI (TIMOB)??? Sorry for n00b questions.

Comment: Appcelerator - INBOX is the project to report new issues. We will move them to the correct project after triage. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: OK done: https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/AC-3450

Comment: Thanks for the excellent ticket and research, which helped us resolve it quickly.